# Соединение процессов в конвейер с использованием неименованных каналов (Linux)

Tags: linux, процесс

Допустим, мы создали канал, с помощью фунции `pipe()`.
Далее создаем левого и правого потомка, поток стандартного вывода левого потомка соединен через канал с потоком стандартного ввода правого потомка.

В общем идея понятна, непонятны детали. Конкретизирую: рассматривая нужные действия для левого потомка, получается такой алгоритм:

*a*. Использовать `close (pipefd[0])`, поскольку читаемый конец канала в левом потомке не нужен.
*b*. Использовать `close(1)`, чтобы закрыть первоначальный стандартный вывод.
*c*. Использовать `dup(pipefd[1])` для копирования записываемого конца канала в дескриптор файла 1.
*d*. Использовать `close(pipefd[1])`, поскольку нам не нужны две копии открытого дескриптора.
*e*. Выполнить `exec` для запускаемой программы.

Пункт *a* логичен. Не понимаю что происходит в пунктах *b* и *c*. Зачем мы закрываем стандартный вывод? Зачем мы используем функцию `dup`? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: На заметку: в пункте _c_ правильнее использовать `dup2(pipefd[1], 1)`

Comment: если быть ещё точнее, то `dup2` следовало бы сделать вместо *b* и *с*, но в данном случае это чисто факультативно...

Answer (score 2):

> Зачем мы закрываем стандартный вывод?

Чтобы не писа́ть в старый дескриптор, унаслледованный от родителя, а также чтобы переоткрыть на его месте трубу в пункте *c*.

> Зачем мы используем функцию dup?

Системный вызов `dup` копирует заданный дескриптор в дескриптор с наименьшим незанятым номером, в данном случае `1`. В результате все действия со стандартным выводом (как `printf`, `puts`, `write (STDOUT,…)` итд) текущего процесса будут оперировать с нашей трубой, а не с тем дескриптором, который был у родителя.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что Вы не очень хорошо представляете суть организации такого обмена:

> Выполнить exec для запускаемой программы.

Это о чём? Какая такая "запускаемая программа" ?

На самом деле, Вы должны сделать нечто иное:

1. Создаём канал с помощью вызова pipe()
2. Создаём левого потомка с помощью fork()

   - Левый потомок закрывает pipefd[0] и начинает писать в pipefd[1]
3. Создаём (в родительском процессе) правого потомка с помощью fork()

   - Правый потомок закрывает pipefd[1] и начинает читать из pipefd[0]
4. Родитель закрывает оба pipefd[] - ему они не нужны
5. Родитель должен повиснуть на ожидании сигнала SIGCHILD, свидетельствующего о завершении одного дочернего процесса.

А вот потомки (оба) действительно, могут выполнять *exec()* для запуска каких=то других программ вместо себя.

Comment: дык в вопросе же подробно описан алгоритм действий левого потомка после `fork`'а, но до `exec`'а т.е. пункт *2*.

Comment: Это понятно, не совсем понимаю, зачем нам необходимо закрывать первоначальный стандартный вывод через close(1)? И в чем смысл  использования dup()? Ну создаем мы копию файлового дескриптора, потом одну из них закрываем и работаем со второй. Зачем это нужно? Почему нельзя после создания левого потомка через fork(), выполнить close(pipefd[0]) и после этого выполнить exec()?

Comment: @chitos95  **Почему нельзя ** - на самом деле, это подстраховка. Вспоминаем о том,  что *fork* передаёт в дочерний процесс КОПИИ файловых дескрипторов родительского. После этого дочерний выполняет *exec()*. Как именно загружаемая программа будет использовать полученные файловые дескрипторы - не знает никто. Поэтому, лучше отказаться от их использования в родительском процессе.